# Remove reversed similar phrases in list of list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are some similar phrases and words in list of list and I wish to remove them.

Original list:

```
lst1 = [['daniel philips', 'philips daniel', 'daniel philips william'],['cherry', 'mary', 'cherry mary']]
```

Looking for output:

```
lst2 = [['daniel philips william'],['cherry mary']]
```

My code:

```
keyword_list = []
for list_a in lst1:
    temp_list = []
    while len(list_a)>0:
        popped_item = list_a.pop(0)
        popped_item = str(popped_item)

        is_subset = False
        for item in list_a:
            if popped_item in item:
                is_subset = True
                break

        if is_subset == False:
            temp_list.append(popped_item)
    keyword_list.append(temp_list)
```

However, it is not giving me the desired results.

Comment: For one, `'philips daniel'` does not appear in `'daniel philips william'`, so your test `if popped_item in item:` doesn't catch it and both get added to the result. It seems like you should be testing if all the parts of a name appear in any of the others, instead of just checking if the whole thing is in there.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular inputs (where there aren't any disjoint names in either list), all you really need is the longest element of each list:

```
>>> lst1 = [['daniel philips', 'philips daniel', 'daniel philips william'],['cherry', 'mary', 'cherry mary']]
>>> [max(s, key=len) for s in lst1]
['daniel philips william', 'cherry mary']
```

To actually determine whether any of the names are subsets of the others, though, turn them into actual `set`s so you can simply compare them and filter out the sets that are subsets of the longest set (or any other set in the list):

```
>>> [[n for n in s if not any(set(n.split()) < set(m.split()) for m in s)] for s in lst1]
[['daniel philips william'], ['cherry mary']]
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for an input like `[['john', 'john doe', 'someone else altogether'], ...]`

Comment: Why not?  (Assuming you want `'john doe', 'someone else altogether'` to be the output, which I'd think you would based on OP's description.)

Comment: @Samwise note that `'john doe'`, and  `'someone else altogether'` are within the same list, so probably should return `'john doe someone else altogether'` while dropping only the `john` as it is the subset.

Comment: @Samwise, if the list of list becomes lst1 = [['daniel','philips','daniel philips', 'philips daniel'],['cherry', 'mary', 'cherry mary']] and I have used your 2nd suggested solution. The output becomes [['daniel philips','philips daniel'], ['cherry mary']]. I was hoping to get [['daniel philips'],['cherry mary']]. Is that possible?

Comment: I'd probably do it by making a second pass -- you'll have to figure out how to pick between the two duplicates!

Answer (score 0):

A fairly explicit solution would be something like this:

```
lst1 = [['daniel philips', 'philips daniel', 'daniel philips william'], ['cherry', 'mary', 'cherry mary']]

result = [[
    name for name in group
    if not any(all(part in other_name.split() for part in name.split()) 
    for other_name in group 
    if other_name != name)
] for group in lst1]

print(result)
```

I quite liked the solution @DYZ posted but then removed though:

```
result = [[max(zip(map(set, map(str.split, group)), group))[1]] for group in lst1]
```

In both cases the result:

```
[['daniel philips william'], ['cherry mary']]
```

However, which one you prefer depends on what you need to happen in this case:

```
lst1 = [['john', 'john doe', 'mary white']]
```

If you need: `[['john doe', 'mary white']]` my solution works, otherwise you might prefer @DYZ if you just want `[['john doe']]` and want to ignore the later `mary white`.

You pointed out that in case there are two names in a list that are the same except for the order, both get eliminated - not what you want. So I gave it some though and I think this meets all requirements:

```
lst1 = [['daniel philips', 'philips daniel', 'daniel philips william'], ['cherry', 'mary', 'cherry mary']]


def single_names(groups):
    result = []
    for group in groups:
        solution = []
        for name in sorted(group, key=len, reverse=True):
            name_set = set(name.split())
            if not any(x | name_set == x for __, x in solution):
                solution.append((name, name_set))
        result.append([x for x, __ in solution])
    return result


print(single_names(lst1))
```

Not as nice and not as fast a comprehension, but I see no way around keeping track of the sets as you're building them - I think this is still fairly clean, using the simplest types.

Comment: if the list of list becomes lst1 = [['daniel','philips','daniel philips', 'philips daniel'],['cherry', 'mary', 'cherry mary']] and I have used your first suggested solution. The output becomes [[], ['cherry mary']].  I was hoping to get [['daniel philips'],['cherry mary']]. Is that possible? I am think the solution is almost there.

Comment: That's a good point, both are excluded because they are the same length, just in a different order - in that case, which one should be preferred? Or just either?

Comment: either will just do fine. Thanks so much